# Python: Split a string into a list, taking out all special characters except '

Tags: python, string

I need to split a string into a list of words, separating on white spaces, and deleting all special characters except for '

For example:

```
page = "They're going up to the Stark's castle [More:...]"
```

needs to be turned into a list

```
["They're", 'going', 'up', 'to', 'the', "Stark's", 'castle', 'More']
```

right now I can only remove all special characters using

```
re.sub("[^\w]", " ", page).split()
```

or just split, keeping all special characters using

```
page.split()
```

Is there a way to specify which characters to remove, and which to keep?

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` as normal, then filter the unwanted characters out of each word:

```
>>> page = "They're going up to the Stark's castle [More:...]"
>>> result = [''.join(c for c in word if c.isalpha() or c=="'") for word in page.split()]
>>> result
["They're", 'going', 'up', 'to', 'the', "Stark's", 'castle', 'More']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

page = "They're going up to the Stark's castle [More:...]"
s = re.sub("[^\w' ]", "", page).split()
```

out:

```
["They're", 'going', 'up', 'to', 'the', "Stark's", 'castle', 'More']
```

first use`[\w' ]` to match the character you need, than use `^` to match the opposite and replace wiht `''`(nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution.

1. replace all chars other than alpha-numeric and single quote
   characters with SPACE and remove any trailing spaces.
2. Now split the string using SPACE as delimiter.

```
import re

page = "They're going up to the Stark's castle   [More:...]"
page = re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z']+", ' ', page).rstrip()
print(page)
p=page.split(' ')
print(p)
```

Here is the output.

```
["They're", 'going', 'up', 'to', 'the', "Stark's", 'castle', 'More']
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `''.join()` and a nested list comprehension would be a simpler option in my opinion:

```
>>> page = "They're going up to the Stark's castle [More:...]"
>>> [''.join([c for c in w if c.isalpha() or c == "'"]) for w in page.split()]
["They're", 'going', 'up', 'to', 'the', "Stark's", 'castle', 'More']
>>>
```